# "assign store views" Dropdown not visible when adding new widget instance

Tags: widgets

So I'm new to Magento, and have been getting to know it's functionality the past week or so. 
Getting the hang of it, but have run into a wall when it comes to adding widget instances. I select which type, then specify which design/package, but there are no other options available. When I then click save, I can name it and specify which area(s) it will appear and the sort order.

Everything I've googled has shown that you must specify which store/site the instance will appear on.

I have checked system>managestores> to see that I have an active site (Pretty sure I do), but that is all I know to do to understand the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.